# Angularjs - $q.all not holding the promises in an sync way

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to use $q.all to wait for the function to finish. I have an example in plunker `http://plnkr.co/edit/uG2JujPqoiBgqtRjEZwh?p=preview`

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="App">
    <div ng-controller="AppController">
        Its the app
        <button ng-click="run()">Run (check console)</button>
    </div>

    <script>
    var App = angular.module("App", []);
    App.controller("AppController", function($scope,$q){

        $scope.xxy = function(num){
            var d = $q.defer();
            for(var i=0;i<100000;i++){
                //do nohing
            }
            d.resolve(num*20);

            var promise = d.promise;

            return $q.all([promise]).then(function(data){
                return data;
            });

        };

        $scope.run = function(){
            for(var i=0;i<10;i++){
                console.log(i);
                console.log($scope.xxy(i));
                //$scope.xxy(i).then(function(r){
                //    console.log(r);
                //})
            }    
        };
    });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The function **xxy()** is the one that is written an **async** way, but i want it to be **sync** using $q.all. Cant change the nature of xxy function, as it will then break other stuff in my big project.
xxy() is an simple version of a big function that i'm using and its build using $q.defer.

So basically i want the output to be: 1 20 2 40... and not as its currently 1 2 .. 20 40...

Comment: plunker or fiddle please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want to serialize the behavior: print 1, call the async function and print the return value 20, and only then run the loop again, print 2, then call the async function and so forth?

This is an interesting question indeed. To me, it seems that you need to use a [repeater pattern](http://www.richardrodger.com/2011/04/21/node-js-how-to-write-a-for-loop-with-callbacks/#.VJQ6AP-d8).

Applied to your case:

```
App.controller("AppController", function($scope,$q,$timeout) {

    $scope.xxy = function(num) {
        var d = $q.defer();

        $timeout(function() {
            d.resolve(num*20);
        }, 1000);

        return d.promise;
    };

    $scope.repeater = function(i)  {
        if (i < 10) {
            console.log(i);
            $scope.xxy(i).then(function(ret) {
                console.log(ret);
                $scope.repeater(i + 1);
            });
        }
    };

    $scope.run = function() {
        $scope.repeater(0);
    };
});
```

See in action: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/masa671/3879qdfe/).

I added `$timeout` to demonstrate async behaviour and to be able to place resolving the promise to the callback where it belongs.

I hope I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I see, the repeater is basicly a recursive function, replaced the $scope with normal functions, so that the angularjs scope checking does not trigger. Does solve the problem that i have in a way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in your run function.... you currently have this commented out....

```
$scope.xxy(i).then(function(r){
  console.log(r);
})
```

but $q.all resolves an array of results (in the order of how the promises are passed in, so you need to use this...

```
$scope.xxy(i).then(function(r){
  console.log(r[0]); // first item of the result array
})
```

**EDIT** Here it is working in an updated [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/RpCDCbS7CalqA7EsMIFG?p=preview)

**From the Documentation** ([link](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q))
Combines multiple promises into a single promise that is resolved when all of the input promises are resolved.
*returns:* An array or hash of promises.

Comment: The output that i want is 1 20 2 40 ... currently the output is 1 2 .. 20 40. I want to use the xxy function as an synchonus call, but i cant change the core of the xxy function in my project because it's too big and can break some other stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.xxy(i)` returns a **promise**.

You can't just loop and wait for a return value. Promises don't work that way.

Instead you have to do this.

```
$scope.xxy(num).then(function(value){
      ...
});
```

`$q.all(..)` wraps all the promises in the array into a new promise.

Comment: So, what can i do to make the function that returns a promise to wait until it's done some code, and then continue normaly. Basicly i need to somehow trick the async function to be sync.